# Is it possible to scale a SVG image using CSS transforms and transitions?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am currently working on my portfolio site. I am using a Javascript to animate the header when scrolling ([this is the tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/06/on-scroll-animated-header/) I have followed).

It basically displays a larger header and logo when you scroll all the way to the top of the page. When you scroll down below 300 pixels it will reduce the height of the header in a graceful manner using CSS transitions. The larger logo will be swapped with a smaller version of the logo (as seen below). The tutorial was not intended for images but I made some small alterations to make it work.

```
.logo {
    display: block; 
    float: left;
    width: 180px; height: 60px;
    margin-top: 29px;
    background: url(../images/logo-large.svg); background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font: 0/0 a; text-shadow: none; color: transparent; 
}

.logo-shrink {
    display: block; 
     float: left;
    width: 90px; height: 30px;
    margin-top: 14px;
    background: url(../images/logo-small.svg); background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font: 0/0 a; text-shadow: none; color: transparent; 
}
```

I am wondering if there is any way that I can apply CSS transforms and transitions to make the swap less jarring? Would it be possible to maybe use a single image and scale it up or down? I apologise if this is a silly question, I am quite new to this :) Please let me know if you need me to provide more details.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Change the width and height gradually using jquery? The image does NOT need scaling; SVG is a vector format.

Comment: Thank you Elliott. I had wrongly assumed that the Transform Scale would change the height and width. Is there a way to gradually change the width and height of the SVG image using CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of swapping the class, just add and remove class `.logo-shrink`. Add CSS transitions in class `.logo`...

```
.logo {
    display: block; 
    float: left;
    width: 180px; height: 60px;
    margin-top: 29px;
    background: url(../images/logo-large.svg); background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font: 0/0 a; text-shadow: none; color: transparent; 
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.logo-shrink {
    width: 90px; height: 30px;
    margin-top: 14px;
}
```

If the animation feels jerky then you can transform and transition on a parent div, as SVG 1.1 does not allow this style to be applied on the SVG tag (though I think it works in Webkit anyways).

Comment: I have tried your suggestion Duopixel, the animation is quite smooth, but the image is being cropped instead of being scaled down. The javascript is currently removing and adding the .logo-shrink class. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Insert the logo with the img tag

Comment: Again, I apologise for my newbieness, but would you be able to spell it out for me? Am I supposed to add the logo in the logo div and remove it as a background in the CSS?

Comment: Try adding background-size: cover; to .logo (sorry for the poor formatting I'm on mobile)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using [CSS3 transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform):

e.g.

```
<svg style="-webkit-transform: rotateZ(30deg); transform: rotateZ(30deg); -moz-transform: rotateZ(30deg);" width="400" height="180">
  <rect x="50" y="20" width="150" height="150" style="fill:blue;stroke:pink;stroke-width:5;fill-opacity:0.1;stroke-opacity:0.9">
</svg>
```

Obviously, you can apply the styling using classes or whatever.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did try to use transform scale on the logo but did not seem to work, but I am probably approaching this the wrong way as Elliot pointed out.